# Crosstab two columns under one column header Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, dataset, crosstab

I want to create a report like [image: required report view] 
in crystal report cross tab. 
The Table has the following data [image: Table Data].

I can get the report with three expected columns like SELF, 50% and 75%.

[image: currently I used]

and their output look like

[image: my output report]

But my requirement is to use Increases and NPCalculated Columns under Main Column as mentioned in pic 1 above. 
Note: I used the NPCalculated in Summarized Fields but It gives me out like NPCalculated Value comes under Increases Value but It should be side by side as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I add NPCalculated column in Summarized field and now I have two summarized fields. Next, right-click one of the summary cells > Summarized Field lables > Summarize horizontally.