# Crosstab - multiple columns into single row header

Tags: crystal-reports, pivot-table, crosstab, crystal-reports-xi

I'm using Crystal Report Version 11.

I'm trying to use the cross-tab to show a table of data but when I add more columns, it is stacking the columns on top of each other. Is it possible to set them all into one row even if I keep adding columns to it.

What it is:

[image: What it is]

What I want:

[image: What I want]

There are 3 columns and 3 summarized fields. I plan to add more to both but still want to keep it in a single columns.

Comment: Are you adding colums or fields to cross tab?

Comment: Can you show the design of the cross tab...that is cross tab expert

Comment: You can not do this?  you can achieve with a sqlserver side, get the data in a single column. this will helpfull - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31019094/crosstab-two-columns-under-one-column-header-crystal-report

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XAG65BV.png

Answer (score 2):

Now Update this
try this way. I hope, help your development.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to put it with the line of 5768S because eventually i want it to be like this 
http://i.imgur.com/OG8uuo4.png

Comment: hey, **2-1/2"** is count 2 (double) so it is showing group such as (36+73=109 and 25+52=77)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XAG65BV.png

This is my current design that isn't allowing me to have rows like yours.